# What is the size of a character packed integer in comparison with its original size?

Tags: string, byte

Suppose that `I` is the size of a `T` integer.
What is the maximum size of a string `S` that contains the digits of `T` arranged into characters?
For example:

```
T = 12345
S = '12345'
```

Comment: It's not, I even thought about including "It's not homework"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the basic equation only works for ASCII characters in ASCII or UTF-8 encoding; one byte per character. For UTF-16, these same characters would be encoded as 2 bytes each, and in UTF-32, 4 bytes each. This matters, depending on the programming language and runtime; .NET strings are stored and encoded in UTF-16.

So, it's actually (log(N) + 1)*sizeof(char)

Answer (score 2):

`log10(T) + 1` will give you the size (in characters) of the string `S`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the log (base10) of I + 1

Thus an int I of 1000 - log I would give you 3 + 1 = 4